# cygwin /dev/input/eventX functionality

Tags: cygwin, evdev, uinput

Does anyone know if cygwin has functionality similar to /dev/input/eventX on linux? The only reference to this I could find online was this: http://polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=input-linux-evdev&tf=2&of=Cygwin&sf=7. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to install this package (or if it is even one I need). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How works in Linux ? The libgii package is available in cygwin https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libgii1/ so you can install with the Cygwin setup

Comment: hmm, never heard of libgii, does anyone even use that library?